# How can I feed this baby hedgehog?

Tags: eating, hedgehog

Two days ago, I found a baby hedgehog. He was very friendly and I have played with him. This morning, I have found him in a bad condition, half bent around / curled up.

Can anybody please tell me how I can feed this animal? I know nothing about it, I am an IT guy.

[image: baby hedgehog]

Comment: give it catfood wet or dry and water,never give milk or milk products(many do this and it kill them).

Comment: I have tried to feed him with carrot, raspberry and tomato. Unfortunately it doesn't eat... Never tied with milk and will not if you suggest.

Comment: it is best to take it to a vet and let the vet tell you what to do.what is best for the animal.

Comment: Are they moving at all?

Comment: Yes it's movig, but the moving is strange... it's going in circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hedgehogs are omnivorous (they eat plants and meat) to feed them use cat food and water.

Wild hedgehogs do always have parasites (internal and external) I suggest you get it dewormed if it is possible.

Don't take it indoors as this might stress the hedgehog.

If possible take a cardboard box and make a hole in it and place it in a shaded place in your garden (hedgehogs sleep during the day and are active during the night).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog

Comment: Thanks, he is now fine. I guess he was hungry and tired. :)

Comment: i am glad to hear it goes well whith the hedgehog :)